# How do you add reactive interceptors to Spring Boot annotated controllers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-messaging, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I've set up rsocket metrics using `rsocket-micrometer` on the **CLIENT** side, by configuring the `RSocketConnector` with interceptors, like this (Kotlin):

```java
    rSocketReqesterBuilder.rsocketConnector { configureConnector(it) }

   // ...

    private fun configureConnector(rSocketConnector: RSocketConnector) {
        rSocketConnector.interceptors { iRegistry ->
            // This gives us the rsocket.* counter metrics, like rsocket.frame
            iRegistry.forResponder(MicrometerRSocketInterceptor(registry, *localTags.toArray()))
            iRegistry.forRequester(MicrometerRSocketInterceptor(registry, *localTags.toArray()))
            iRegistry.forConnection(MicrometerDuplexConnectionInterceptor(registry, *localTags.toArray()))
        }
    }
```

But on the **SERVER** side, I'm using an annotated (`@MessageMapping`) Spring Boot RSocket Controller, like this (Java):

```java
    @MessageMapping("replace-channel-controller")
    public Flux<TransformResponse> replace(Flux<String> texts) ...
```

Here, I'm not explicitly in control of the connector.
How do I add interceptors on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@Configuration
public class RSocketConfig implements RSocketServerCustomizer {

    private final MeterRegistry registry;

    public RSocketConfig(MeterRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(RSocketServer rSocketServer) {
        rSocketServer.interceptors(
                iRegistry -> {
                    log.info("Adding RSocket interceptors...");
                    iRegistry.forResponder(new MicrometerRSocketInterceptor(registry, tags));
                    iRegistry.forRequester(new MicrometerRSocketInterceptor(registry, tags));
                    iRegistry.forConnection(new MicrometerDuplexConnectionInterceptor(registry, tags));
                }
        );
    }
}
```